# Нарубать или нарубить?

Tags: грамматика, грамотная-речь

"Можно и капустки **нарубать**" - подтвердите, плиз, что это некорректное употребление глагола, и правильно было бы сказать "Можно и капустки **нарубить**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нарубить** капустки - нормативное выражение со значением "измельчения рубкой". Есть и просторечно-разговорная форма в виде глагола "*рубать*" с приставочными и бесприставочными вариациями. Это глагол имеет два разных значения: 1) *рубить* (чаще шашкой, но бывает, что и уголь) - это значение фиксируется напр. словарём Ушакова как региональное (пометка "обл."), 2) *есть* энергично, в изрядном количестве и с видимым удовольствием (широко распространённое жаргонное значение). В сочетании со съедобной "капустой" будет, скорее всего, ассоциироваться только второй вариант, что не только звучит просторечно, но может и привести к неправильному пониманию смысла. Поэтому выражение "наруб**а**ть капустки" (наесться капусты) вместо "наруб**и**ть капустки" (в смысле её приготовления) было бы крайне неудачным.

Answer (score 0):

В словарях (например, Малом академическом) указывается, что *наруб**а**ть* — это глагол несовершенного вида, составляющий пару глаголу *наруб**и**ть* (ср. *измельч**а**ть* и *измельч**и**ть*). Форма, возможно, не отвечает современной литературной норме, но тем не менее существует. Другое дело, что в таком случае "нарубать", скорее всего, глагол строго переходный, и правильно будет *нарубать капустк**у***, а не *капустк**и***.

Comment: Действительно, можно исходное выражение изменить под "Можно и капустку нарубать", но смысл изменится радикально: вместо "можно капустки (к салатику) нарубить" получится что-то вроде профориентации - "кем быть" :) Можно водить пароходы, капустку в тиши нарубать иль продавать пиво-воды - настала пора выбирать!

Answer (score 0):

наруба́ть
    несов. перех.

1.
    Рубя, приготавливать что-либо в каком-либо (обычно большом) количестве.  2.
    Срубать что-либо в каком-либо (обычно большом) количестве.

3.
    Вырубая, добывать породу в шахте в каком-либо (обычно большом) количестве.

> Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.